# Erro de CORS ao realizar requisição utilizando HttpClient no Angular

Tags: angular, http-headers, cors, httpclient

Estou tentando realizar uma requisição Http utilizando "HttpClient" do Angular 4, e recebo o seguinte erro:

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

De acordo com as pesquisas que fiz e com o que conheço de CORS teria que informar no Header da requisição o origin, minha dúvida é. Qual a forma correta de realizar está requisição obedecendo as regras de CORS utilzando o Angular?

Tentei o seguinte código:

```
public get(url: string, params: HttpParams) {

    let options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200'),
        params: params

    }

    return this.http.get<any>(url, options);
}
```

Estou utilizando a seguinte url "http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/locale/3477/hours/72?token=XXXXX", mas ao tentar com outros serviços o mesmo erro ocorre.

Tentei substituir 'http://localhost:4200' por '*' e não obtive sucesso

Comment: o seu servidor permite requisições cross-origin?

Comment: O servidor que estou tentando acessar permite sim, é a api de previsão do tempo do Clima Tempo, mas estou fazendo a chamada a principio de um servidor local, apenas levantei um servidor local com "ng serve", preciso fazer alguma configuração local tbm?

Comment: pelo que entendi olhando a documentação dessa api você deve gerar um *token* e habilitar o cors por lá. Na sua aplicação angular você deve então anexar esse *token* gerado

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pelo empenho em ajudar e eu já fiz isso, "http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/locale/3477/hours/72?token=XXXXX", eu só troquei o token por XXXXX, o problema é que eu tentei consutar outros serviços e tive o mesmo erro, por isso estou achando que configurei errado os headers da requisição

Comment: Quer dizer que a previsão de 72 horas por ID da cidade funcionou mas nenhuma outra requisição funcionou? Pode dizer quais outras requisições você tentou?

Comment: Pois a meu ver todas as requisições disponíveis nessa api são requisições get, aonde os parâmetros são passados pela url. Dessa forma, você só precisa concatenar `&token=your-app-token` em cada um dos `http.get` para essa api

Comment: Nenhuma requisição funcionou, nem nessa serviço do clima tempo, nem em outro serviço, como o Open Weather API, parece ser algo muito simples mesmo, concatenei o token e fiz um get, mas aparece o erro de cors, mesmo eu setando no header da requisição, vc sabe se existe outra forma de configurar o header? Sem ser dessa forma:

".set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72868/discussion-between-mercador-and-horrander-maikel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando a documentação da [API de meteorologia da Climatempo](http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/doc/index.html), após o *token* ter sido gerado, basta você concatená-lo ao final da URL usada para cada requisição HTTP:

```js
public get(url: string, params: HttpParams) {    
    return this.http.get<any>(url + "token=" + this.token, options);
}
```